# mod_rewrite - make business.php to become folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Making .htaccess (mod_rewrite) work has been very difficult 
I already have this script for friendly url in my .htaccess file 
and that works perfect

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/(.*)/(.*)$ news_id.php?newsid=$1
```

But now I want to hide my file extension in the main navigation...
..so `mypage.com/business.php` will become `mypage.com/Business`

I was told to add `RewriteRule ^business$ business.php [L]`

...but it doesn´t cut it and Google has blacklisted me for searching

Could it be I have to add something to the button in my html/php file?
...this is the button 
`<li class="nav-business"><a href="business.php"></a></li>`

I think the php-file doesn´t connect to my .htaccess but that can´t be because
this first Rewrite rule works

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to try ^business/?$ as a rewrite.

Comment: Hey if you think my answer is right can you mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try something like this.To remove the .php extension from a PHP file for example yoursite.com/wallpaper.php to yoursite.com/wallpaper you have to add the following code inside the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: I would like to add that if the user navigates to `mysite.com/thispage.php` it will still show as `mysite.com/thispage.php`. However, if you ensure all links are stripped of the PHP extension, it will display correctly.